# Visual Studio project template with custom wizard

Tags: visual-studio, templates, vsix, project-template, vsixmanifest

I'm trying to create a custom wizard in a Visual Studio project template to open a new tab loading a web page with a getting started guide for the user of the template.

I've been following this guide: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185301.aspx

The problem I'm facing is this:
[image: screenshot of error message]

This error message pops up when running the experimental instance and creating a new project using the template. I'm typing the error message here for search engines:
*Error: this template attempted to load component assembly 'SomeWizard, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=token'. For more information on this problem and how to enable this template, please see documentation on Customizing Project Templates.*

I've reproduced the error in a GitHub repo here: https://github.com/eloekset/VSProjectTemplateWithWizard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your GitHub repo I can see a couple of issues:

- SomeWizard should be a VSIX project, not a class library
- The EivindTemplate project should only contain template functionality, at the moment it contains wizard functionality as well. An example is the .vsixmanifest file which should be moved to the SomeWizard project. As your .vsixmanifest is located in the wrong project, the ProjectTemplate asset will not be registered correctly.

I forked your repo and refactored the code: https://github.com/karolikl/VSProjectTemplateWithWizard (remember to set SomeWizard as the startup project and set the Debug settings as you explained yourself on GitHub before running it)

Comment: I downloaded your project and it won't deploy because VS says that the wizard project is a class library. Were you ever able to get it to work?